# What is the period of $y = k$, where k is any constant?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, periodic-functions

This question stemmed from a larger question:

Determine if the following expression is periodic or aperiodic. If periodic, state it's functional period.

$$f(x) = 2\sin(\frac{2\pi{x}}{7}) - \cos(\frac{3\pi{x}}{5}) + \tan(\frac{3\pi{x}}{2}) - 3x + 3[x] + 4$$

We can further express it as

$$f(x) = 2\sin(\frac{2\pi{x}}{7}) - \cos(\frac{3\pi{x}}{5}) + \tan(\frac{3\pi{x}}{2}) - 3\{ x \} + 4$$

We know that,

Period of $y = 2\sin(\frac{2\pi{x}}{7})$ - $7$

Period of $y = \cos(\frac{3\pi{x}}{5})$ - $\frac{10}{3}$

Period of $y = \tan(\frac{3\pi{x}}{2})$ - $\frac{2}{3}$

Period of $y = 3\{ x \}$  - $1$

But what is the period of $y = 4$? Shouldn't it be indeterminate, since the function repeats itself after every iteration, and we can't determine the gap between any 2 iterations?

To determine the fundamental period of $f(x)$, we need to know the periods of all the functions in $f(x)$, and take their LCM.

It's quite counter intuitive, since we know $y = 4$ is periodic, yet we can't determine it's period.

I plugged $f(x)$ into Desmos, and it gave me this, leading me to believe $f(x)$ was aperiodic..[image]

This is the function I plugged into Desmos: $2\sin\left(\frac{2\pi x}{7}\right)\ -\ \cos\left(\frac{3\pi x}{5}\right)\ +\ \tan\left(\frac{3\pi x}{2}\right)\ -\ 3\operatorname{mod}\left(x,1\right)\ +4$

However, in an attempt to salvage the situation, I decided to neglect the $y =4 $ term and calculate the fundamental period, which I was getting as $70$ (LCM of $7, \frac{10}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, 1)$.

I checked the graph again, and it seems to be correct!

Graph when $x = 0$: [graph at x = 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qdQm.png)

Graph when $x = 70$: [graph at x = 70](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z502G.png)

Here's my question: What is the period of $y = 4$, or $y = k$, where k is any constant?

Comment: The only variables in your expression are in $-3x + [x]$. Did you mean for $x$ to be in the trig expressions? If not, they are all constant, so your function is really of the form $f(x) = C -3x + 3[x]$, which has period 1 since it increases on $(0,1)$ and $[x+1] = [x] + 1$.

Comment: Did you mean to write $f(x) = 2\sin(\frac{2\pi x}{7}) - \cos(\frac{3\pi x}{5}) + \tan(\frac{3\pi x}{2}) - 3x + 3[x] + 4$? This seems to be what you're trying to plot in Desmos. I also think your plot on Desmos isn't quite right. It looks like you forgot to add $3\,\operatorname{floor}(x)$. But also, sums of periodic functions can have very large periods, so you shouldn't always expect to be able to spot the periodicity in Desmos!

Comment: Also: The sum of two periodic functions needn't be periodic. Consider $g(x) = \sin x + \sin\pi x$. There are further requirements regarding their periods if the sum is to be periodic.

Comment: @MPW Yes I did, let me make that edit right away.

Comment: Finally: Constant functions are periodic, but they have no minimal period.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I figured that $-3\{ x \}$ was the same as $-3x + 3[x]$, but I'll input the original expression and see if the graph is different.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen You are right, I'd made a mistake in writing the expression in Desmos, I made the change, and got an answer as 70.

Comment: @BongoMan, interesting - I am unable to even get a graph of a function if I try to plot $3\{x\}$, for example. In Desmos, curly brackets are used for [piecewise functions](https://cl.desmos.com/t/how-can-i-graph-a-piecewise-function-in-desmos/4874). PS: to check if a function has period 70 in Desmos, I would do something like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ugyo0yox3u). (Try toggling the second graph on and off).

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Enter the command: $3\operatorname{mod}\left(x,1\right)$, it's the equivalent of $3\{x\}$. I was actually also having this trouble, but found out about this hack for fractional part graphs from reddit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y=k$ is periodic with any period that you wish.  When you are combining periodic functions and looking for the period you can ignore it.  Compare $\sin x$ and $1+ \sin x$.  The period of both is $2\pi$.

In your case you need a period that is a multiple of all the individual periods.  The smallest one is $70$ so your graph is not long enough to show a period.  It is a hard function to plot because the tangents go off to infinity so often.  I doubt that if you plot over a range of $150$ you will be able to see the periodicity by eye, but you can try.

Comment: Yes! This is fully correct. I still find it odd how ignoring the $y = 4$ function nets us the correct answer, but I'm not complaining :)

Comment: It might be useful to think of asking "Is $y=k$ periodic with period $70$?  The answer is clearly yes, regardless of the period you ask about.  It therefore does not change the period of the expression it is added to.

Comment: True, that makes perfect sense!